# Quarkus 3 + Hibernate 6 error on packages

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I updated my Project to Quarkus 3 and I am getting this error

```
Association 'com.step.trackactions.model.PlatformActionLeadEntity.company' targets an unknown entity named 'com.step.common.model.Company'
```

`PlatformActionLeadEntity` is made like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PlatformAction")
@RegisterForReflection
public class PlatformActionLeadEntity{

    private Customer customer;

    private Company company;

}
```

and both Company and Customer are tagged as entity

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "Company")
@RegisterForReflection
public class Company extends PanacheEntityBase implements Cloneable { ... }
```

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "Customer")
@RegisterForReflection
public class Customer extends PanacheEntityBase implements Cloneable { ... }
```

the point is that

- `com.step.trackactions.model.PlatformActionLeadEntity` is inside the project
- `com.step.common.model.Company` is in an external library imported in the project

and in `application.properties` I added

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=com.step
```

but it dies not work, with the old version of quarkus he used to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it is the annotation `@MappedSuperclass`. You cannot annotate a class with `@Entity` and `@MappedSuperclass`